# How can i get values of input sent to api on ok button of ant design modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, antd

I'm trying to implement a kind of table, which has an add button that opens a modal.

Inside the modal, I have the inputs that I want to update in the table, but using the ant design modal it has an ok button and a cancel button. How do I make the path to get the values? I'm having trouble understanding/writing this syntax. Can someone help me?

on the "onOk", i don't know how to write the function, tried creating a onSubmit(values) and console.log it but it doesn't show

Here's the code

```
    function showModal(nome,colunas) {
    setFormDisplay("");
    setModal(!modal);
    setFormName(nome);
    setFormColumns(colunas);
  }

  function cancelModal() {
    setFormDisplay("none");
    setModal(false);
    setFormName("");
    setFormColumns([]);
  }


    <>
      <div className="">
        <CardsHost posts={nomes} />
        
      </div>
      <Modal
        visible={modal}
        onOk={} 
        title="Novo Prontuário"
        onCancel={cancelModal}
        style={{display:`${formDisplay}`}}
        width={1000}
        
      >
      

      {formColumns.map((column,index) => (
        <>
          <div className="labelll">
            <label key={`label-${index}`}>{column.title}</label>

              {(column.key !=='proc' && column.key !== 'meds' ) 
                ?  <Input key={`input-${index}`} style={{ width: "61.3%" }} />
                :  (column.key == 'proc' ) ? <div className="pesquisa-input"><Demo /></div>
                :  <div className="pesquisa-input"><PageComponentMeds /> </div>
               }
               
            
              
           
            
          </div>

          

           {/*<div className="labelll">
            <label> Data de Atendimento</label>
            <DatePicker style={{ width: "61.3%" }} />
          </div>

          <div className="labelll">
            <label> Nota </label>
            <TextArea style={{ width: "61.3%" }} />
      </div> */}
        </>
      ))}
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be use to add a state variable for both of your input values. You can update them using the `onChange` callback provided by the antd components. On submit you use the state values to make your api call.

Make sure that you reset the variables on cancel and after a successful call.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: You introduce the state variables using `const [textState, setTextState] = useState<string>('');` and pass the `textState` to your text area like this: `<TextArea style={{ width: "61.3%" }} value={textState} onChange={e => setTextState(e.target.value)} />`.